# Matrix function to operate on the whole matrix as a filter to determine mines in neighbouring cell

Tags: python

I have to create a minesweeper game using python which is part of codesignal INTRO challenges

I have tried out a code but its not applying to last row and last column
I have tried this code but its not working and I am not able to figure it out why this issue is occuring

```
import numpy as np

matrix = [[True,False,False,True], 
 [False,False,True,False], 
 [True,True,False,True]]

def minesweeper(matrix):
    re=np.zeros((len(matrix),len(matrix[0])))
    for i in range(len(matrix)-1):
        #print(i)
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])-1):
            #print(j)
            if (j==0) and (i==0):

                re[i][j]=matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i+1][j]+matrix[i+1][j+1]

            elif (j==len(matrix[0])-1)and(i==0):
                re[i][j]=matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i+1][j]+matrix[i+1][j-1]

            elif (i==len(matrix)-1)and (j==0) :
                re[i][j]=matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i-1][j+1]+matrix[i][j+1]

            elif (i==len(matrix)-1)and(j==len(matrix[0])-1):
                re[i][j]=matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i-1][j-1]

            elif (i==0 and j!=0) or (i==0 and j!=len(matrix[0])-1):
                re[i][j]=matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i+1][j-1]+matrix[i+1][j]+matrix[i+1][j+1]

            elif (i==(len(matrix)-1) and j!=0) or (i==(len(matrix)-1) and j!=len(matrix[0])-1):
                re[i][j]=matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i+1][j]+matrix[i+1][j-1]+matrix[i+1][j+1]

            elif  (j==0 and i!=0)and (j==0 and i!=len(matrix)-1):
                re[i][j]=matrix[i+1][j]+matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i+1][j+1]+matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i-1][j+1]
            elif (j==len(matrix[0])-1 and i!=0) and (j==len(matrix[0])-1 and i!=len(matrix)-1):
                re[i][j]=matrix[i+1][j]+matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i+1][j+1]+matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i-1][j+1]

            else:
                re[i][j]=matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i+1][j]+matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i-1][j-1]+matrix[i+1][j-1]+matrix[i-1][j+1]+matrix[i+1][j+1]
    return re


minesweeper(matrix)


Output should be 
[[0,2,2,1], 
 [3,4,3,3], 
 [1,2,3,1]]

But I am getting 
[[0., 2., 2., 0.],
       [3., 4., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

Comment: Try to force "int" type in output value. You may try to use:

"return int(re)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `range(len(matrix)-1)` `range(len(matrix[0])-1)` not include last column and last row, and I think if you process boundary problem separately, the logic is very complex, you can put them together, visit 8-neighbors and check boundary uniformly, like this:

```
def minesweeper(matrix):
    re = np.zeros((len(matrix), len(matrix[0])))
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            for I, J in (i - 1, j - 1), (i - 1, j), (i - 1, j + 1), (i, j - 1), (i, j + 1), (i + 1, j - 1), (
            i + 1, j), (i + 1, j + 1):
                if 0 <= I < len(matrix) and 0 <= J < len(matrix[0]):
                    re[i][j] += matrix[I][J]
```

output:

```
[[0. 2. 2. 1.]
 [3. 4. 3. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3. 1.]]
```

and I think np.zeros is not suitable here, you can just use 2d-list:

```
re = [[0] * len(matrix[0]) for _ in range(len(matrix))]
```